# I am getting the error in below JSON format "Expecting 'STRING', got '{'"

Tags: json, validation

I am getting error while validating the below JSON. Can you please explain why ? In JSON, can't we put one curly braces inside another ?

```
{
"header":{
"appId":"xxyy"
,"token":"token"
,"messageId":"messageId"
}
,{
"message_timestamp":"2022-12-07 11:35::44"
,"wins2rms":{
"data_ind":"NONSELLABLE"
,"data_row":6
,"data_set":[
{
"loc":"9981"
,"loc_type":"W"
,"item":"00000160"
,"qty":20
,"reason":"Q"
,"rms_ind":"Y"
}
]
}
}
}
    

    Error: Parse error on line 6:
    ...": "messageId"   },  {       "message_timesta
    ---------------------^
    Expecting 'STRING', got '{'


Thanks
```

Comment: Indent your code for readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that the JSON object you have provided is not valid. In JSON, objects are represented using curly braces ({ and }). You cannot put one set of curly braces inside another, as you have done on lines 6 and 7.

Here is how the JSON object should be formatted:

```
{
    "header":{
        "appId":"xxyy",
        "token":"token",
        "messageId":"messageId"
    },
    "message_timestamp":"2022-12-07 11:35::44",
    "wins2rms":{
        "data_ind":"NONSELLABLE",
        "data_row":6,
        "data_set":[
            {
                "loc":"9981",
                "loc_type":"W",
                "item":"00000160",
                "qty":20,
                "reason":"Q",
                "rms_ind":"Y"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In this version of the JSON object, the nested objects are properly formatted, with each object enclosed in its own set of curly braces. You can use a JSON validation tool to verify that the object is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused while validating is because of JSON syntax error. We can  use nested JSON objects but, the it is used are not a valid syntax.

In the following JSON object 6th and 7th line has an syntax error. You cannot but one set of curly braces inside another with an comma.

```
,"messageId":"messageId"
}
,{
"message_timestamp":"2022-12-07 11:35::44"
```

In above object can modified as.

```
,"messageId":"messageId"
}
"message_timestamp":"2022-12-07 11:35::44"
```

We can use curly braces inside another with an comma in an array of JSON object. Below is an example that showcases how it can be used.

```
{
    "array":[
           {
              "name":"test1"
           },
           {
              "name":"test2"
           },
           {
              "name":"test3"
           },
    ]
}
```